# Prime asymptotics from Euler product

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is said that the Euler product $$\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$ diverges as $s \to 1^+$ proves we can't find constants $C$,$\theta$ with $\theta < 1$ such that $\pi(x) < C x^\theta$ because that would imply that the product converges for $s > \theta$.

I don't understand this deduction at all, how is the fact about the prime counting function concluded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking logs of the Euler product, expanding out the resulting series, and comparing all the higher-order terms (i.e. terms involving $p^{-ns}$ for $n > 2$) to the *convergent* series $\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} m^{-2s}$, we find that
the divergence as $s \to 1^{+}$ is equivalent to the divergence of the series
$\sum_p p^{-s}$ as $s \to 1^{+}$.  Now if $\pi(x) < C x^{\theta}$, then
the $n$th prime would have size $\sim n^{1/\theta}$, and so 
this series would behave like $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{- s/\theta},$ which
converges as $s \to 1^+$ (because $1/\theta > 1$), a contradiction.

Comment: Matt, isn't the connection between pi(n) and the size of the n-th prime true only in average (so that the last sentence of the answer is correct, if read as an Abel summation or Tauberian argument)?

Comment: @zyx: Dear zyx, I didnt' think carefully about the argument for the last sentence; I think you are right that some kind of Tauberian argument might work, or perhaps if one takes into account a suffciently strong error term in the PNT?  Best wishes,